# Magento 2. Copy files from elastic search map to custom theme in Magento

Tags: magento2, elasticsearch

Has someone worked this out?

I would like to copy the css file located in

`/app/code/Wyomind/Elasticsearch/view/frontend/web/css/autocomplete.css`

to my custom theme folder `(app/design/frontend/... map).`

What should be the right location in my custom theme to save the file? I tried

`app/design/frontend/XX/theme-frontend-default/Wyomind_Elasticsearch/styles/autocomplete.css`

but that did not work. Do you have any tips?

Comment: Do you have a less file?

Comment: Did you try the my answer ?

Comment: I have tried it but not tested yet. As soon as I know, I will let you know.

Comment: accept the answer If you find It helpful @JulianMurillo

Answer (score 0):

Your `autocomplete.css` file path should be like this,

```
app/design/frontend/[Namespace]/[theme]/Wyomind_Elasticsearch/web/css/autocomplete.css
```

don't forgot to remove your cache storage and `static-content` deploy command